# Strapi custom controller execute from Admin UI

Tags: strapi, headless-cms

I'm extending a create controller for one of my models:

```
async create(ctx) {
    let entity;
    if (ctx.is('multipart')) {
      const { data, files } = parseMultipartData(ctx);
      entity = await strapi.services.complaint.create(data, { files });
    } else {
      entity = await strapi.services.complaint.create(ctx.request.body);
    }
    const sanitized = sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.complaint });
    strapi.emitToAllUsers('complaint::created', sanitized);
    return sanitized;
  },
```

It works fine if I do the request from Postman for example, but is it possible to do the same if the user creates the new object from the Admin UI?

When I see the console from Strapi when I send the request from Postman:

```
debug POST /complaints (58 ms) 200
```

But, if I create a new object from the admin UI I see this instead:

```
debug POST /content-manager/explorer/application::complaint.complaint (1017 ms) 200
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible? I'm using latest Strapi version (v3)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute something from Admin UI, I think you might want to look at how to implement it in models using lifecycle hooks.

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#models

From what I know, controller only called on API, while service are a set of reusable functions. Models are called both by API and Admin UI.

complaint/models/complaint.js

```js
module.exports = {
  lifecycles: {
    afterCreate(result, data) {
       strapi.emitToAllUsers('complaint::created', result);
    }
  }
};
```

You can also create a function in service and call it models lifecycle hooks.